# Creating mobile version website

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a mobile website version for my website, and I'm wondering whether should I make a new mobile website and put it a subdomain or I should just modify the existing desktop version to be able to work on mobile phones.

Comment: You can create a simple mobile version of your site with [Media Queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: Google "responsive design".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend duplicate content because unless you are doing it right with canonical tags (and know what you are doing) you can take a nosedive with SEO ratings. Google itself suggests using a responsive layout (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details).

With utilities like Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation frameworks, you can quickly build a site that works in desktop and mobile. You also can learn responsive techniques such as media queries and breakpoints fairly quickly, although it is helpful if you are skilled with CSS.

As long as the original site isn't built in tables, you should be able to convert to relative widths (percentages) for mobile if needed.

The real benefit of responsive design is you don't need to limit the experience based on a user's chosen platform to view a site, but rather optimize it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a script named Mobile-Detect from github and create header footer and some custom php code for mobile version and use php if...else to switch between pc and mobile.
Or use responsive design. If use responsive design then don't forget include media="handheld" on header.